# How to use @document rule to exclude certain sites from applying rules to?

Tags: css

I want to make it so my rules apply by default to all the sites/pages except the ones I list.

Sort of like an opposite of `@document domain(mozilla.org)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@document

edit:[follow-up regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177138/regexp-to-exclude-websites)

Comment: I'm firing in the dark, but does `:not()` work?

Comment: @Pranav Kapoor: It doesn't, because `:not()` only works as a selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an easy way to do this currently, as noted in [this CSS Conditional Rules draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-conditional-20120911/#at-document) with a link to a Mozilla bug report:

> This syntax doesn't offer any ability to do negations, which has been requested in [Mozilla bug 349813](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=349813). Use cases that people have wanted negations for include:
>
> - User style sheets that want a particular rule in general, but know that that rule does more harm than good on specific sites.
> - Authors who have a rule that they want to apply to most of their pages, but wish to make a few exceptions for.

Hopefully, they'll propose and implement such a feature soon.

In the meantime, you may be able to achieve something with `regexp()` which accepts a JavaScript regex with certain flags — details are included in the spec — but I can't make any guarantees.

Answer (score 1):

```
@document regexp('.+mydomain\\.com\/(?!nope|nah).+') {
    .someClass{}
}
```

This will match `mydomain.com` while excluding `mydomain.com/nope` and `mydomain.com/nah`

In your case `regexp('https?://(?!domain1|domain2|domain3).+')` perhaps.

---

https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-conditional-20120911/#at-document

> **Note that regular expression must match the entire URL, not just a part of it.**
>
> For example, this rule:
>
> `@document regexp("http://www.w3.org/TR/\\d{4}/[^/]*-CSS2-\\d{8}/") {
>    body { font-size: 20px ! important }
>   }`
>
> changes the font size of the body element for pages such as http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/PR-CSS2-20110412/.
>
> Note that the backslashes in the regular expression require CSS escaping as `\\`.

---

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@document

> [Initially](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-conditional-20120911/#at-document) in [CSS Conditional Rules Module Level 3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-conditional-3/), @document has been
>   [postponed](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-conditional-20121213/#changes) to Level 4.