# regexp to exclude websites

Tags: css, regex

I want to use [`@document regexp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@document) rule [to exclude certain sites from applying rules to.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175899/how-to-use-document-rule-to-exclude-certain-sites-from-applying-rules-to) What can I use as a regexp to do this?

Comment: Could you give some examples of the domains you want excluded? JS has negative lookahead, so I am wildly assuming it works for CSS too.

Comment: Try `^(?!http:\/{2}example\.com).+`

Comment: `^(?!.*IgnoreMe.*).*$` as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/831989/1266650) works too.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to this question? I answered your previous question and seem to have missed this one. You'll need to provide more details though, like which domains you're specifically trying to exclude.